# How to grep for an exact match of a string?

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to find exact matches in a file that matches the string "1.2.0" (the numbers 1 and 2 and 0 with a single dot inbetween them). I am trying this as follows:

```
cat  /my/file.log | grep "1.2.0"
```

but this matches also expressions like

```
112.0
1,200
1,270
11200
172.0
```

So how to match exactly the string I want to match?

Comment: try escaping the dots ... i.e. `grep "1\.2\.0"`